# Watson Speech To Text Latency

Tags: websocket, speech-to-text, watson

Using WebSockets to connect to STT.  Working well for the most part.
When streaming a half hour newcast to Watson STT I find respose time to
be 1 to 2 seconds on average.  Periodically I experience much longer delays.
8 seconds, 10 seconds.  Sometimes things get really backed up and the delay can
be as much as 60 seconds or more!  Has anyone else experienced this behavior ?
Does anybody have a suggestion on how to overcome this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad. There can be any number of factors that can impact latency. If you can reproduce on demand, update your question with sample code of what you are doing, but more likely if that is a case you would be better off opening a support ticket in bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

the event you are reporting is not something that we IBM Watson are aware of. Our customers are typically very happy about the latency of the Speech-to-Text service. Can you please contact technical support through this link so we can get to the bottom of this?  https://support.eu-gb.bluemix.net/gethelp/

btw. if you can provide the transaction-id of one of those transactions in which you experienced long delays that would help very much with troubleshooting.

Answer (score -3):

> Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Yes.

> Does anybody have a suggestion on how to overcome this problem? Thanks!

Use self-hosted Kaldi-based transcriber.